# How do you average the power spectra across multiple samples to compare 2 conditions?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, averaging

I have physiological signals from samples under 2 conditions and want to compare the difference in frequency content between the conditions. Specifically,I'd like to compare the average power spectrum of condition A and condition B to evaluate if there are any differences. Both sets of signals are sampled at 1000 Hz. Also, if the signals are of differing length, is it sufficient to just truncate to the shortest length? I'm trying to accomplish this in Python.

Any help would be awesome, thank you.

Comment: 1.  the thinking behind averaging to see the difference? 
2. Have you heard of [coherence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(signal_processing))?

Comment: I have physiological signals from 100 samples in condition A and 100 samples in condition B. I'd like to compute average power spectrum for Condition A and Condition B and plot them both. I'm thinking I could use coherence after I've computed the average spectra for both conditions, right?

Comment: So my main question is how do I compute the average across all samples in a given condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the average spectrum, simply compute each individual spectrum with the same frequency precision and average them together.

To achieve this, you can zero pad each signal before taking the FFT to make sure they all have the same length. Whichever library you are using, there’s usually an option for that, for [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fft.html#scipy.fft.fft).

Comment: Should I zero-pad each signal or truncate to the shortest length? Zero padding could introduce additional variations, right?

Also, I was thinking of applying the signal.welch() function from scipy and then averaging Pxx via arithmetic mean across all signals? See here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html. 

Would this work or am I missing something?

Comment: You can do either, but yes, truncating to the shortest length is "safer". Depends on how short and what you want your frequency resolution to be.
As far as Welch, you don't need to do this since you're already averaging a bunch of spectra together, which will take care of the noise.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by " As far as Welch, you don't need to do this since you're already averaging a bunch of spectra together, which will take care of the noise"? I need to calculate Pxx of each signal and then average via a simple arithmetic mean, right? What noise are you referring to?

Comment: In short, Welch's method is one of many methods to estimate $P_{xx}$. It trades frequency resolution for estimation noise variance reduction. The noise reduction is attained thanks to the averaging of multiple spectra together (successive windows of the signal under analysis). In your case, you have the luxury of having access to multiple realizations of the same process. You can therefore keep your frequency resolution intact by computing a periodogram (i.e. power spectrum) of each realization, and averaging (arithmetic mean, yes!) the results to reduce the estimation noise variance.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the thorough explanation, it was really helpful! One last question - should I be normalizing to the max. peak of Pxx (the PSD) to shift everything relative to 0 db?

Comment: Either for each spectra or after averaging all spectra?

Comment: Definitely not before averaging.

Comment: Why not before averaging? If I take each PSD of a signal and then normalize the average PSD to the max. peak, I get a lot of NaN values toward the end.

Comment: What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, imagine you have spectrum 1 with one peak at 50Hz with amplitude 1000 and nothing at the other frequencies, and spectrum 2 with max peak at 51Hz and amplitude 10 and nothing at the other frequencies. If you normalize both before averaging you'll get an average with two peaks of the same amplitude, one at 50Hz, one at 51Hz. Maybe that is what you want after all, at this point it's a matter of what you're using this average spectrum for. But if you're confident that each time series has the same scale, it could be a problem.

Comment: For the NaNs, I dont know how you're doing your normalization so can't help you there.

Comment: This could be worthy of a new question by the way. I jumped the gun a little with the "definitely not before averaging". There are situations where you might want to do that. I just don't have enough information on your problem to answer.

Comment: Got it, the example you gave makes sense. Need to figure out what I want to illustrate exactly. Thanks for all the clarification, this was immensely helpful.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help ;)